# tar: compress & remove original files & leave directories untouched

Tags: bash, find, tar

I am in a directory containing:

f0
f1
f2
.h1
.h2
.h3 
/tmp

I want to tar tar all files and erase original files. I do not want to tar /tmp, nor touch its files.Following post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/tar-files-only-no-directories, it looks like there is no straight forward way to perform this, so I tried the following:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar cvf test.tar {} --remove-files \;`

it almost works:

-the archive is created

-all files are erased

-/tmp stays untouched

but

there is only file f2 in my archive (!)

I found a very uggly solution though:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar cvf test.tar {} \; && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.tar' -exec shred -xuvz {} \;
```

but something more elegant would be very much appreciated.

thanx folks!

Comment: What makes this post [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here on stackoverflow.com, instead of [the Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) that you linked to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar cvf test.tar {} --remove-files \;
> ```

almost works, but

> there is only file f2 in my archive (!)

Yes, because the `-exec` command is executed separately for each file `find` discovers, and the `c` option to `tar` causes it to create a new archive every time.

There are several ways to approach this, but for a not exceedingly large number of files, you can combine `find` with `xargs` to run a single command on all the files selected by `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs tar cvf test.tar --remove-files
```

That's a good pattern to know, but it does have a few limitations.  In particular,

- `xargs` will combine many arguments read from its standard input into a smaller number of commands, but there are system- and data-dependent limits on how many can be formed into a *single* command, which is what you need.  If those limits are exceeded then `xargs` will dispatch multiple commands, which would put you back where you started.  But those limits are typically much larger than are needed for the example case.
- File names with whitespace in them will break this pattern, because xargs ordinarily splits its input at whitespace.  If you have a `find` and `xargs` that support it, however, then you can work around this by using the `-print0` predicate in the `find` command and the `-0` option to `xargs`, together.  Of course, it's not an issue in the first place if you don't have any such file names.